# Access Denied happen on a member of site owner of SharePoint Site

Tags: permissions

I have a SharePoint permission issue, the server is in domain environment.

I try to login by computername\localuser which is a member of site owner, but access is denied. But I can login by domain\domainuser for this site, which also is a member of site owner group.

Answer (score 1):

The local user is not imported to SharePoint User Profiles. Hence you are unable to login using local user account.

You can add local users who belongs to the SharePoint server but not users on the remote client machines. Alternatively using SharePoint User Profiles you can create users and use that for login.

Answer (score 0):

You can propably bypass the active directory and use the ms sqlserver login accounts. Please check the link below [SHAREPOINT 2013 LOGIN WITHOUT ACTIVE DIRECTORY](http://howtoconfig.org/windows/sharepoint-2013-login-without-active-directory/)